# Ruby unable to load after installing TotalTerminal through brewcask with boxen

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv, boxen, homebrew-cask

After running Boxen with a

```
package { 'totalterminal':
  provider => 'brewcask',
  install_options => ['--appdir=/Applications'],
}
```

directive, my system Ruby is unable to load libraries, including builtins like Set, rendering commands like `ruby`, `irb`, `bundle`, `gem` etc., completely unusable and Boxen unable to run:

```
mba2:~ nrser$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

mba2:~ nrser$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

mba2:~ nrser$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

mba2:~ nrser$ ruby -e ''
Could not find mini_portile-0.5.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

`irb`, `gem` and `bundle` all immediately fail with the same error.

If I put the RBenv stuff back in the path (by sourcing `/opt/boxen/env.sh`), I get an even weirder fail, where Ruby can't find the Set module:

```
mba2:~ nrser$ echo $PATH
bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/opt/boxen/rbenv/bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:node_modules/.bin:/opt/boxen/nodenv/shims:/opt/boxen/nodenv/bin:/opt/boxen/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin

mba2:~ nrser$ which ruby
/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims/ruby

mba2:~ nrser$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

mba2:~ nrser$ ruby -e ''
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- set (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/index.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:168:in `fetch_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

This is the second box this has happen on, though both boxes use very similar manifests. Both are on OSX 10.9.3.

My guess is that this has something to do with the TotalTerminal installer restarting the Terminal app during its installation, terminating Boxen/Puppet.

Does anyone have any idea what's gone wrong, or how i can repair my Ruby?

I don't really care that much about having TotalTerminal install through Boxen, but no Ruby is basically a broken machine for me.

Comment: It looks like you've stomped on your (Apple-installed) Ruby. "[Is it possible to reinstall/fix Mac OS X's system ruby without doing a complete OS reinstall?](http://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete/175858#175858)" might be useful to get it fixed, then I'd suggest you *not* try the same thing again if this is the second box it's happened to.

Comment: yeah... that was sort of where i ended up... both times. i reinstalled the OS. i still have no idea how or what happen, but hopefully this info being out there will save someone else the hours i poured into it. tl;dr: don't install TotalTerminal via brewcask on boxen.